# Python + Selenium -- Unable to locate image element (Can't click image)

Tags: python, selenium

[image]I'm trying to create a macro that opens up all my online classes on Chrome (cause logging in is annoying, especially if you have to do it 8 times every morning).

BTW, I use Python 3.8, Chrome 81.0.4044.122, and the latest version of Selenium.

Until now, I clicked button using:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("PATH_OF_ELEMENT").click()`

And then I find a login button that has a image instead of text.
I tried XPath, CSS Selector, id, name, the link of text, ActionChains (move_to) nothing works.

Here's the HTML:
[here click me please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqWj5.jpg).

The button I'm trying to press is the one with the tag a.

I spent 30 minutes googling about this and all I found was Stack Overflow questions from 6 years ago. They suggested I use WebDriverWait or change the frame. None of them worked (I might have made a mistake). I'm new to Selenium so please be kind and explain hard stuff.

How can I find the correct XPath of an image button and click it?

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nice-select').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TqqQ.png)/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqWj5.jpg)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TqqQ.png)/div/ul/li[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqWj5.jpg)").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TqqQ.png)/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqWj5.jpg)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqWj5.jpg)/div/span').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TqqQ.png)/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqWj5.jpg)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqWj5.jpg)/div/ul/li[19]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TqqQ.png)/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqWj5.jpg)/div[3]/div/span').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TqqQ.png)/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqWj5.jpg)/div[3]/div/ul/li[3]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TqqQ.png)/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqWj5.jpg)/div[4]/div/span').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TqqQ.png)/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqWj5.jpg)/div[4]/div/ul/li[3]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TqqQ.png)/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqWj5.jpg)/div[5]/a').click()

Comment: provide more info: example code, website etc.. we cannot guess what you have tried and what is actually the website implementation.

Comment: Thats not the point, I just need to be able to find the correct Xpath  and click the image.

Comment: are you looking for this? //a/img[@src and @alt='mypicture']

Comment: I tried driver.find_element_by_css_selector('//a/img[@src and @alt=mypicture).click() It says selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.122)

Comment: Put your HTML in your question. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, I did put the HTML

Comment: Seems like it a login page.Can you share your url?

Comment: down in the answer comment section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following CSS Selector:

```
.my_menu>a
```

Code should look like:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".my_menu>a").click()
```

Also, try to locate the element with explicit wait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".my_menu>a"))).click()
```

I have tested with the following code block (as result will be displayed popup with 2 options):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://oc31.ebssw.kr/onlineClass/search/onlineClassSearchView.do?schulCcode=00898&schCssTyp=online_mid")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".my_menu>a"))).click()
time.sleep(5)
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".my_menu.active>a"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.122)

Comment: @Jooney, share your URL in this case. Thanks.

Comment: https://oc31.ebssw.kr/onlineClass/search/onlineClassSearchView.do?schulCcode=00898&schCssTyp=online_mid

Comment: @Jooney, check out my updated answer. I have tester it and it works. Thanks.

Comment: TIMEOUT EXCEPTION ERROR

Comment: When I make a sperate py file with your code, it works, but in my code it doesn't work

Comment: In this case, you can accept my answer, because I fixed your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Ratmir, can you dm me in discord? tag: Acecuber32#5026

Comment: ?? Check your code carefully -- look what you could miss.

Comment: Ratmir, I posted my code on the Question, check it out